# dotCMS in Jelastic cloud (define jdbc url)

Tags: jelastic

I've tried to follow this article http://docs.jelastic.com/jelastic-dotcms-deploy  , but actually when I started application I get an error:

SEVERE: Exception starting filter URLMapFilter
com.dotmarketing.exception.DotRuntimeException: org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.)

I understand that there is a problem with jdbc url  , but I can't fix it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is your JDBC URL at the moment?

Comment: Now , I have test account in Jelastic and my domain is env-giph.j.rsnx.ru , so my url is  url="jdbc:mysql://mysql.env-giph.j.rsnx.ru/dotcms"

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for clarifying.

Your JDBC URL should be like this:

```
jdbc:mysql://mysql-env-giph.j.rsnx.ru/dotcms
```

Note the `mysql-` not `mysql.`

EDIT: http://docs.jelastic.com/connection-to-mysql may help to clarify it further (in the docs, the environment name is "mysqlconnection", so they use "mysql-mysqlconnection" for the MySQL server.

The format is always like this:

```
host=jdbc:mysql://mysql-{your_env_name}.{hoster_domain}/{db_name}
```